# Execute sikuli in command line?

Tags: java, sikuli

I tried to excecute a pptx file with sikuli slides in command line:
I tried this:
c:\Program Files\Sikuli-Slides\java -jar sikuli-slides-1.4.0.jar execute Test.pptx

The pptx file is in the folder C:\Program Files\Sikuli-Slides
When i execute the commadn line i have the following error:
File does not exist: C:\Program%20Files\Sikuli%20Slides\Test.pptx
Execution failed because java.io.IOException

I have Sikuli Slides program in windows which is working well.
I created the Test.pptx file which is working with Sikuli Slides but not in command line.

And I cannot generate the java code for Test.pptx file too

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First you have to export you Sikuli project (create .skl of project).

After, run command line as Administrator and insert the follow prompt:

```
Sikuli-IDE.bat -r C:\Path_to_sklFile\Filename.skl (enter)
```

If in your sikuli script you have input parameters:

```
Sikuli-IDE.bat -r C:\Path_to_sklFile\Filename.skl --args arg1 arg2 argN (enter)
```